# Inheriting properties of Imported asset from a swf file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I would like to copy x, y position of a button located in swf file and I get it in flex project somehow and keep those properties. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. :)  Care to elaborate on your question?  Perhaps give some examples of what you've tried, or a problem you are facing?